# R packages for MS-SSIM?

Tags: r, image-processing, similarity, image-quality, ssim

I wanted to do some simple image comparisons with R (the reason I am not using python is that the workflow is in R).  I tried to search for ms-ssim implementations in packages in R, but did find any except for `spatialcompare::msssim`.  However, as I mentioned in my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66346949/why-ssim-implementations-by-different-r-packages-yield-drastically-different-res) yesterday, I figured out that the result of this function might not be correct for my input (could be related to `matrix` to `raster` transformation?).  Are there any more suggestions for appropriate ms-ssim codes?  I actually self-implemented one based on `SpatialPack::SSIM` because it seems easy to just downsample the image again and again, but am not sure if I am writing it correctly.  I'll put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

My demo code for a very simple ms-ssim:

```
calcMSSSIM<-function(Mat1,Mat2){
  weight = c(0.0448, 0.2856, 0.3001, 0.2363, 0.1333)
  level<-5
  array<-c()
  ssim<-SpatialPack::SSIM(Mat1, Mat2, alpha=1, beta=1, gamma=1,
                    eps=c(0.01,0.03), L=max(tmp1,tmp2))$SSIM  
  array[1]<-ssim$comps["contrast"]*ssim$comps["structure"]
  result<-abs(array[1])^weight[1]
  for (i in 2:level) {
    tmp1 <- EBImage::resize(tmp1, w=dim(tmp1)[1]/2, filter="none")
    tmp2 <- EBImage::resize(tmp2, w=dim(tmp2)[1]/2, filter="none")
    ssim <- SpatialPack::SSIM(tmp1,tmp2,alpha=1, beta=1, gamma=1, 
                             eps=c(0.01,0.03), L=max(tmp1,tmp2))$SSIM
    array[i]<-ssim$comps["contrast"]*ssim$comps["structure"]
    result <- result*abs(array[i])^weight[i]
  }
  lum<-ssim$comps["luminance"]
  result<-result*lum^weight[i]
  return(list(array,result))
}
```

Is it correct?